# sIFR3 r437 font generator / is r437 better?

Tags: html, css, sifr, sifr3

So since I've got major problems with the sIFR3-mousescroll issue in sIFR3 r436, I wanted to find out if that problem has been solved in the newest update. But the problem is that the new version tells me the *.swf I'm using is only compatible with r436. I've used sifrgenerator.com to create my font. Is there a newer converter, or another way to convert my .ttfs?

Oh and it would be nice if someone could tell me if the new sIFR update solves the scrolling-problem!

Thanks!

Comment: I know this isn't the exact answer to your question but have you font squirrel's font face kits.  It works so much better than sifr, and you don't have these issues because it's text not flash.  http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface